# Mousewheel Event Over Object Tag

Tags: javascript, html, svg, mouseevent, mousewheel

I am using object tags to embed svg images into some html. I've noticed that when I have a mousewheel event and the cursor is over one of these object tags, the event is not fired. This happens both when the event is attached to the object tags parent element (or directly to the body etc) and for testing purposes I also tried attaching a mousewheel event directly to the object (not to scroll the actual tag, but just to return a console log for testing) it does not work either.

Apparently object tags somehow kill page events and do not bubble the events!?!

Is there a way around this? It really kills the usability of a page, when the mousewheel scrolling suddenly stops if the cursor lands over an object tag.

I am using Firefox and have not tested this in other browsers. None the less, I need to support Firefox regardless.

**UPDATE:**
This bug may only affect Firefox in Linux. A small percentage, which is good, but none the less that percentage includes me so a workaround is necessary. If I embed svg in an img tag it works fine, however that prevents a default fallback to png for ie < ie9 so its not really a great solutions.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? I am having the same problem with SVG objects in Safari.